# how to display a list inline using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu using html, I have added my link  in an unordered list (ul) has shown below. In my css i added a display:inline; to the links so that they would display in a link like a menu but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="offers.php">Special Offers</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="staff.php">Meet Our Staff</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: li{ float: left;} or li {display: inline-block;}

Comment: @becky : should the list-items be left/right aligned? Should they fill the entire line with space in between?

Comment: @fcalderan, 'display: block'  will fill entire line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are targeting the anchors, which are already inline by default. I believe you mean to target the list items:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v8r9eouf/)

Answer (score 1):

You were **very** close!

The only thing wrong with your code, is that `display: inline;` should be on your `<li>` elements instead of your `<a>` elements :

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="offers.php">Special Offers</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="staff.php">Meet Our Staff</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r5Lxz51r/1/))

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `ul li { float: left; padding-right:10px; }`

https://jsfiddle.net/n4aak3nk/1/